# Installing Visual Studio's SQL Server express later

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I installed VS2010 Ultimate while ago whithout installing SQL Server Express. I also installed SP1 and Lightswitch over it.

Now I changed my mind. I tried add/remove features but now that option is not available any more. What can I do about it?

Comment: You can't just install SQL Express off of Microsoft's website??

Comment: I'm not sure which version comes shipped with VS2010

Comment: @djechelon, I'm quite sure that it is the 2008 one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

On VS2010 Ultimate installer, I cannot found on add/remove resources/features any option to add/remove SQL Server Express...

[image: options to add/remove]

### Solution 1

Browse the DVD contents. On `\WCU\SSE` you can find the SQL Server Express x86 and x64 installers:

[image: \WCU\SSE]

### Solution 2

Go to [Microsoft.com > Download Center > Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695), download and install SQL Server Express.